# "Unable to resolve your shell environment"

Tags: visual-studio-code

On macOS Big Sur, I installed MacPorts and installed bash using it. I set my default shell to the MacPorts version of bash `/opt/local/bin/bash` by using `chsh`.

All was well.

I decided I would rather use Homebrew. I uninstalled MacPorts, installed Homebrew, installed bash via homebrew, and set my default shell to `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash` via `chsh`.

All was well, except when I am first starting vscode (from Finder) which reports:

```
Unable to resolve your shell environment: A system error occurred (spawn /opt/local/bin/bash ENOENT)
```

This is a totally reasonable complaint, since that binary no longer exists. It makes this complaint when launched from Finder, but not when launched from the terminal. There is no reference to this prior version of bash in my user `settings.json` file, nor is it in my `.bashrc`.

Where the heck could vscode be getting this path to bash from?!

Edit (2021-10-11): there is something strange going on here. If I open an integrated terminal in vscode:

```sh
$ echo $SHELL
/opt/local/bin/bash
$ ls -lh $SHELL
ls: /opt/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory
$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
45388 ttys001    0:00.12 /bin/bash -l
```

(there are no such problems in the regular macOS Terminal app)

Edit again (2021-10-12):

- I tried resetting vscode (via `rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code`).
- I tried resetting vscode's cache (via `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.*`),
- I downloaded iTerm2 and ran it; it loaded the correct shell (`/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`) without issue (tried this in hopes of determining if there was some other setting in macOS pointing at the old macports version of bash).

Comment: There are a few settings in the `settings.json` config file (cmd+Shift+P) that you can try: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-the-taskdebug-profile

Comment: I have tried setting various combinations of those, which all seem to work as expected, but do not resolve my initial problem.

Comment: same issue here when I uninstalled Fish Shell. Don't know how to fix.

Comment: I have a similar issue - I have installed VSCode for all users, then running from a second user where I installed bash via homebrew inside the user home folder - VSCode (run from Apps) is still looking for another path (the old `/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`, where I had it before installing homebrew separately for the two users).

Comment: I am happy/sorry to report that this has mysteriously stopped happening on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and was able to resolve this by changing the shell for the logged in user (using `chsh -s`, cf. the hint at the bottom of  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139867). As this change is not being picked up by VSCode in your currently logged in session, don't forget to explicitly log out and log back in again after performing this step.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I was able to solve it changing the shell for my user to another one, for example, `/bin/bash`.

I was trying to update it using the `chsh -s` command, but I was getting a PAM error. So, the trick I did was to open the file `/etc/passwd`, search the line of my username, and at the end change manually the obsolete terminal, in my case `/bin/zsh`, to the default (`/bin/bash`) or to a new one.

After that, just log out and log in, and issue solved!

Answer (score 0):

After changing the default shell to the new one (`chsh`, System Settings.app, Directory Utility.app, ...) logout and re-login solved the issue for me